# Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting TCPWRAP

Tags: jestjs

we are using Jest for unit-testing. we use sequelize ORM. we initially has a class that initialized and exported sequelize like so:

database.ts:

```
export const sequelize = ...
```

Jest gave us no issues with this code. we were calling `sequelize.close()` after completion of all tests.

Then we had to revise the code like so (since we have multiple modules that plug into our main application):

database.ts

```
export { sequelize } from 'common'
```

Now Jest gives us this warning at end of tests:

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TCPWRAP

    > 1 | export { sequelize } from 'common'
        | ^
      2 |

      at Connection.connect (node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:43:17)
      at Client._connect (node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:113:11)
      at Client.connect (node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:162:12)
      at BoundPool.newClient (node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:232:12)
      at BoundPool.connect (node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:207:10)
      at BoundPool.query (node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:394:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/common/src/index.ts:14:6)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/database/sequelize.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/database/index.ts:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/initdb.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/foo.spec.ts:1:1)
```

any idea why and how we can fix this?